# Speedtest is found down in Prometheus

Tags: docker-compose, prometheus

I used this [docker-compose](https://github.com/dipan29/internet-monitoring) (kinda basic), however after configuring it and building it I got after entering `http://[server-ip]:9090/targets` information that:

```
speedtest (0/1 up)
Error: Get "http://speedtest:9798/metrics": dial tcp: lookup speedtest on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
```

And I understand that it can't find that host, it's just that the configuration itself wasn't touched and it actually looks legit to me:
docker-compose

```
service:
   speedtest:
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    expose:
      - 9798
    ports:
      - 9798:9798
    image: miguelndecarvalho/speedtest-exporter
    restart: always
    networks:
      - back-tier
```

prometheus.yml

```
- job_name: 'speedtest'
    metrics_path: /metrics
    scrape_interval: 5m
    scrape_timeout: 60s # running speedtest needs time to complete

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['speedtest:9798']
```

Can someone spot the issue? How the speedtest is not found on local DNS server? Everything is exposed and still not finding the right stuff.

#Edit I have DNS server configured by `dnsmasq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Prometheus is bound to the host's network and you're trying to access `speedtest` on the host's network too, then you should reference `speedtest` as `localhost` **not** `speedtest`:

```
static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9798']
```

> **NOTE** Docker (Compose) only provides DNS resolution for e.g. services (i.e. `speedtest`) within the process. If you were to run Prometheus within the Docker Compose services too, then you'd be able to use Docker (Compose) DNS resolution to resolve `speedtest` to the container on port `9798`.